How to mock @Value attribute in Spring Boot
in SpringBoot I have this Service to test:
@Service
public class CardService{

    @Value("${max_transactions}")
    private int maxTransactions;
   
    public boolean addTransaction(Transaction transaction){
       if(transaction.value < maxTransactions){
          ...

          return true;
       }
    }

    ...
}

When I create a unit test on this function maxTransaction = 0 even if the value in the application.properties is different.
class MatchesServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    CardService service;

    @Test
    void testAddTransaction(){
      
       Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
       transaction.value = 10;
       
       assertTrue(service.addTransaction(transaction))
    }
}

How to inject application.properties value in the private field?
I've try to find something online but I found nothing,
Thanks in advance.

As you aren't using Spring for the test nothing will be injected because well no Spring. It is Mockito that is creating an instance not Spring here, so no injection, value replacement or other Spring features will apply.

you can use the @SpringBootTest annotation to load the application context and @Autowire to inject your class under test. Here's an example where CardService is the class being tested. The test configuration includes a property setting for maxTransactions.
@SpringBootTest(classes = CardService.class, properties = {"maxTransactions=10"})
class MatchesServiceImplTest {

@Autowired
private CardService cardService;

// Test methods go here

}

If you just want to set the value for testing use ReflectionTestUtils :
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;

class CardServiceTest {

@InjectMocks
CardService service;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service, "maxTransactions", 100);
}

@Test
void testAddTransaction() {
    Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
    transaction.value = 10;
    
    assertTrue(service.addTransaction(transaction));
  }
}

